# how to map custom domain name against IP address and port

Tags: networking, dns, port-forwarding, port, domain-name

How to map `custom domain name` e.g. `chat.server.com` to `chat.server.com:9090`. I  actuly want to map `custom domain name` like shown above with having typing to `port no`. Just like i type localhost and `Apache` redirects to `localhost:80`. I am using window 10 laptop. Also i am using `wampp server` on it. Also i use `Openfire server` on it. I like to assign custom domain to open fire. Any, idea...

Answer (score 0):

Wampp is Apache+MySQL+PHP+PERL under Windows. It is a powerful website integration package.

So if we need to change the port, we need to modify the apache configuration file.

If your domain name uses https, you need to change the Listen 443 in the http-ssl.conf file to the required port. If your domain name uses http, you need to change the Listen 80 in the httpd.conf file to the required port.

Most applications have specialized configuration files to modify the corresponding ports, but some of the programs have fixed ports, which are designed in programmer programming and cannot be changed.

We can try to do a port mapping to modify the port, as follows:

Open a command prompt, for example (Map 11111 of 10.10.10.10 to port 80 of 10.10.10.10) :

**Increase port mapping:**

Netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenport=11111

listenaddress=10.10.10.10connectport=80

connectaddress=10.10.10.10

**Delete the port mapping:**

Netsh interface portproxy del v4tov4 listenport=11111

listenaddress=10.10.10.10

**View existing port mappings:**

Netsh interface portproxy show v4tov4

**You can check if the port is listening by command:**

netstat -ano|find "11111"

**Test whether the port is connected:**

telnet 10.10.10.10 11111

Comment: But how if i want third parties apps like `open fire` which uses `9090 port` or may be `Gitea` which uses port `3000` & `Bitbucket` which uses port `8000`. How to map these like custom domains e.g. `openfire.com`, `gitea.com`, `bitbucket.com`. with out using ports in domain name.

Comment: I edit the reply. Please see the above reply.

Answer (score 0):

In short, you don't. An `http://` address without ports always goes to port 80, period. You can't map this through DNS.

You can configure Apache as a "reverse proxy" so that it accepts requests on port 80 for various domains, then forwards them to Openfire on 9090, to Gitea on 3000, and so on depending on the domain. (Search this site for older posts about the same thing.)

But if you want the website to work without a port being specified, *something* has to serve it on port 80 (and 443 for https).